# TFS branch from existing project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

In TFS I have branch on my name but when this branch is make its maybe after 2 week and I have a many changes on this project.My questions is how to upload my change project in this branch to can merge MAIN and my project without errors?

Comment: You can check in your changes to the "your" branch, like normal, and then merge changesets to the main branch using Team Explorer.  Check out this link for merging in TFS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475900(v=vs.100).aspx#MergePlugIn

Answer (score 0):

You need to check-in your changes to the branch first, then merge the branch back to main via the Source Control Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is to first check in your changes into your branch (Pending Changes), den commit these changes.

Afterwards you have to Merge with your MAIN branch, but be sure to first review your changes with the branch you are merging with.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181428.aspx

If you encounter errors, this official Microsoft resource will help you to resolve errors that can happen after a 2 week difference.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181432.aspx

Something that you should never forget: Before Merging with the target branch of your desire, GET LATEST
microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155787(v=vs.120).aspx